# Serialization Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization

i am trying to save a state of a chessGameplay.

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// menu strip control
{
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";

    DialogResult result= saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        saveToFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    }

}

private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";

    DialogResult result= openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        openFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
GameSave game2 = new GameSave();
public void saveToFile(string s)
{
    game2.setLoadedPieces(codeFile.PieceState());// will pass the current pieces state. that is an array of all the chess pieces objects..which determine where each piece is on the board
    FileStream f = new FileStream(s, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();

    b.Serialize(f, game2);// throws here an exception.Type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Pieces' in Assembly 'ChessBoardGame, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
    f.Close();
}

public void openFile(string s)
{
    FileStream f = new FileStream(s, FileMode.Open);// will open the file and the stream
    BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
    game2 = (GameSave)b.Deserialize(f);// will load the stream
    f.Close();
    codeFile.setPieces(game2.getLoadedPieces());// sets the board to the loaded pieces.
    PrintPieces(game2.getLoadedPieces());//prints the existing loaded pieces.
}


[Serializable] 
class GameSave
{
    Pieces[,] pieces;


    public void setLoadedPieces(Pieces[,] serializedSavedPieces) // set the pieces array  to be saved
    {       
        this.pieces = serializedSavedPieces; 
    }
    public Pieces[,] getLoadedPieces() // returns the pieces array
    {
        return pieces;
    }

}
```

Type of exception:

> Type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Pieces' in Assembly 'ChessBoardGame, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Hello Dmitry. It is customary on StackOverflow to accept answers (by clicking the checkmark) once one is satisfactory. You have asked 14 question (including this one), but only accepted one. It is possible that some people will refuse helping you if you continue. Please read the FAQ for more information.

Comment: i gave acceptance tick yesterday, and i will give today

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget your past questions. They also matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you should mark WindowsFormsApplication1.Pieces as [[Serializable]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) ? :)

Comment: it wont let me make the namesepace serliazable. and i have one static array Pieces type, which is in one class that i put the attribute serializable above,

Comment: never mind, now it works. i had to put serializable attribute above a few classes that i have and now it works!!!!